# Having trouble rearranging multiple GGPLOT2 graphs and moving/resizing scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, gridextra

I am working with a dataset consisting of different plant genotypes, rates of fertilizer applications, and 5 different measurements.  I am using `ggplot2` to produce multiple bar graphs, and then using the `gridExtra` package to combine multiple graphs onto a single page. The trouble I am having involves moving and resizing the scale so that there is only one scale for each of my graphs, and I would like to move it to the lower right corner of the graph. The data/code below should better explain what I mean.

Packages/Dataset

```
#Open packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#Dataset
plantdata <- data.frame(genotype = c(1,
                                     1,
                                     1,
                                     1,
                                     2,
                                     2,
                                     2,
                                     2,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     2,
                                     2,
                                     1,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     1,
                                     3,
                                     2,
                                     2,
                                     1,
                                     1,
                                     1,
                                     2,
                                     2,
                                     1,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     3,
                                     2,
                                     1,
                                     2,
                                     1),
                        rate=c(1,
                               2,
                               3,
                               4,
                               1,
                               2,
                               3,
                               4,
                               1,
                               2,
                               3,
                               4,
                               2,
                               4,
                               1,
                               1,
                               3,
                               2,
                               3,
                               4,
                               1,
                               3,
                               4,
                               2,
                               2,
                               1,
                               3,
                               3,
                               4,
                               1,
                               3,
                               2,
                               4,
                               1,
                               2,
                               4),
                        measure1=c(958,
                                   309,
                                   750,
                                   43,
                                   20,
                                   868,
                                   905,
                                   674,
                                   64,
                                   151,
                                   677,
                                   144,
                                   803,
                                   485,
                                   707,
                                   881,
                                   684,
                                   222,
                                   399,
                                   507,
                                   4,
                                   690,
                                   831,
                                   574,
                                   104,
                                   238,
                                   378,
                                   897,
                                   63,
                                   154,
                                   582,
                                   641,
                                   750,
                                   855,
                                   194,
                                   55),
                        measure2=c(359,
                                   728,
                                   180,
                                   614,
                                   241,
                                   989,
                                   117,
                                   101,
                                   95,
                                   156,
                                   227,
                                   355,
                                   597,
                                   50,
                                   636,
                                   912,
                                   149,
                                   862,
                                   897,
                                   601,
                                   176,
                                   7,
                                   182,
                                   214,
                                   453,
                                   569,
                                   124,
                                   113,
                                   969,
                                   781,
                                   713,
                                   613,
                                   800,
                                   334,
                                   435,
                                   748),
                        measure3=c(639,
                                   304,
                                   891,
                                   317,
                                   869,
                                   901,
                                   723,
                                   267,
                                   837,
                                   923,
                                   171,
                                   991,
                                   107,
                                   309,
                                   733,
                                   705,
                                   819,
                                   807,
                                   346,
                                   447,
                                   891,
                                   957,
                                   359,
                                   323,
                                   846,
                                   944,
                                   400,
                                   548,
                                   327,
                                   48,
                                   677,
                                   624,
                                   564,
                                   854,
                                   658,
                                   343),
                        measure4=c(805,
                                   24,
                                   624,
                                   675,
                                   261,
                                   437,
                                   601,
                                   129,
                                   733,
                                   172,
                                   746,
                                   586,
                                   142,
                                   243,
                                   103,
                                   779,
                                   612,
                                   870,
                                   84,
                                   881,
                                   850,
                                   456,
                                   255,
                                   52,
                                   228,
                                   492,
                                   556,
                                   66,
                                   670,
                                   682,
                                   736,
                                   178,
                                   568,
                                   501,
                                   229,
                                   500),
                        measure5=c(667,
                                   105,
                                   565,
                                   724,
                                   238,
                                   861,
                                   299,
                                   13,
                                   171,
                                   759,
                                   755,
                                   557,
                                   739,
                                   228,
                                   870,
                                   595,
                                   793,
                                   790,
                                   572,
                                   590,
                                   365,
                                   974,
                                   550,
                                   766,
                                   441,
                                   265,
                                   245,
                                   909,
                                   150,
                                   88,
                                   473,
                                   245,
                                   340,
                                   378,
                                   998,
                                   121))
```

Function for standard error of the mean:

```
sem <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
```

Generating the graphs:

```
#Measurement 1 graph
meas1 <- select(plantdata, genotype, rate, measure1)

#Aggregating data frame
meas1_mean <- aggregate(meas1, by=list(meas1$genotype, meas1$rate), mean)
meas1_sem <- aggregate(meas1, by=list(meas1$genotype, meas1$rate), sem)

g1 <- ggplot(meas1_mean, aes(x=Group.1, y=measure1, fill=factor(Group.2)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  xlab("Genotype")+ylab("Measurement")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= meas1_mean$measure1, ymax=meas1_mean$measure1+meas1_sem$measure1), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  ggtitle("Plant Measurement 1")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='PRGn', name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
####################################################################

#Measurement 2 graph
meas2 <- select(plantdata, genotype, rate, measure2)

#Aggregating dataframe
meas2_mean <- aggregate(meas2, by=list(meas2$genotype, meas2$rate), mean)
meas2_sem <- aggregate(meas2, by=list(meas2$genotype, meas2$rate), sem)

#Generating graph
g2 <- ggplot(meas2_mean, aes(x=Group.1, y=measure2, fill=factor(Group.2)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  xlab("Genotype")+ylab("Measurement")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= meas2_mean$measure2, ymax=meas2_mean$measure2+meas2_sem$measure2), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  ggtitle("Plant Measurement 2")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='PRGn', name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
####################################################################

#Measurement 3 graph
meas3 <- select(plantdata, genotype, rate, measure3)

#Aggregating dataframe
meas3_mean <- aggregate(meas3, by=list(meas3$genotype, meas3$rate), mean)
meas3_sem <- aggregate(meas3, by=list(meas3$genotype, meas3$rate), sem)

#Graph
g3 <- ggplot(meas3_mean, aes(x=Group.1, y=measure3, fill=factor(Group.2)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  xlab("Genotype")+ylab("Measurement")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= meas3_mean$measure3, ymax=meas3_mean$measure3+meas3_sem$measure3), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  ggtitle("Plant Measurement 3")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='PRGn', name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
##############################################################

#Measurement 4 graph
meas4 <- select(plantdata, genotype, rate, measure4)

#Aggregating dataframe
meas4_mean <- aggregate(meas4, by=list(meas4$genotype, meas4$rate), mean)
meas4_sem <- aggregate(meas4, by=list(meas4$genotype, meas4$rate), sem)

#Graph
g4 <- ggplot(meas4_mean, aes(x=Group.1, y=measure4, fill=factor(Group.2)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  xlab("Genotype")+ylab("Measurement")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= meas4_mean$measure4, ymax=meas4_mean$measure4+meas4_sem$measure4), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  ggtitle("Plant Measurement 4")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='PRGn', name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
################################################################

#Measurement 5 graph
meas5 <- select(plantdata, genotype, rate, measure5)

#Aggregate dataframe
meas5_mean <- aggregate(meas5, by=list(meas5$genotype, meas5$rate), mean)
meas5_sem <- aggregate(meas5, by=list(meas5$genotype, meas5$rate), sem)

#Graph
g5 <- ggplot(meas5_mean, aes(x=Group.1, y=measure5, fill=factor(Group.2)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.6, position="dodge", col="black")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  xlab("Genotype")+ylab("Measurement")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= meas5_mean$measure5, ymax=meas5_mean$measure5+meas5_sem$measure5), width=0.2, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  ggtitle("Plant Measurement 5")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette='PRGn', name= 'rate', labels=c("1","2","3","4"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Then, I arranged all the graphs onto one page, as follows:

```
grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4, g5,
             nrow=2, ncol=3)
```

The output:
[image]

Because the requirements for this graph are that it needs to be exported in a smaller format, I would like to re-arrange the scale so that there is only one scale for the whole combined image, and I would like to increase the size of it. See below:
 [image]

How can I do this? If there is a better way to generate this than the way I did it, I am open to learning how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `ggpubr` package and in there the `ggarrange` function with the argument `common.legend = TRUE`.

```
a <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), group = gl(5,20))
b <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), group = gl(5,20))
c <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), group = gl(5,20))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(b, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(c, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + geom_point()

ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, common.legend = TRUE)
```

Documentation: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggarrange.html

Comment: That did it. Thank you!